# Jquery dyamically inserting function pointers into event listeners

Tags: dynamic, listener, jquery, function-pointers

Using Jquery, I would like to dynamically generate a listener and the actions to be carried out by each listener.

The problem is that the pointer to the dynamically chosen function, below `func[i]`, is never replaced by the the content that it represents (in this case any of the functions stored in the `func` array).  It seems clear that this is happening because JS doesn't go inside the `function(){...}` until the listened for `click` takes place.

I'm not sure of how to solve the problem and any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  Below is some sample code and if you like here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D6fLd/).  Many thanks!

```
// an array of functions to call and a random number to choose which one to call
var func = ["Alf();","Sarah();","Jon();"];
var i = Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 );

// the dynamically generated listener
$('#foo').on('click', function() {
  func[i];//pointer to function
});

// a function to be called
function Alf () {
    alert("Hi! I'm Alf");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your array to function references not strings:

```
var func = [Alf, Sarah, Jon];
```

And, change your execution of it to:

```
// the dynamically generated listener
$('#foo').on('click', function() {
  func[i]();//pointer to function
});
```

And, you'll need to make sure that your variable `i` retains its value until the event actually occurs and `i` is a dangerous variable name to use for that.

---

I'd suggest this:

```
(function() {

    // an array of functions to call and a random number to choose which one to call
    var funcArray = [Alf, Sarah, Jon];
    var randomFunc = funcArray[Math.floor( Math.random() * func.length )];

    // the dynamically generated listener
    $('#foo').on('click', function() {
      randomFunc();   //pointer to function
    });

    // a function to be called
    function Alf () {
        alert("Hi! I'm Alf");
    }

})();
```

Changes:

1. Put the whole thing in an IIFE so your variables are protected and not global
2. Get the actual random function rather than just the index
3. Use `func.length` instead of `3` for maintainability.
4. Use a better name for the random function variable
5. Change functions to function references instead of strings.
6. Add parens to end of `randomFunc()` to actually execute the function

---

If you want to make this into a function that allows you to use the logic in multiple places, you can do something like this:

```
function bindRandomClickFunc(selector, fnArray) {
     var fn = fnArray[Math.floor( Math.random() * fnArray.length )];
     $(selector).on('click', fn);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense.  I however would like to be able to use this method for a variable number of listeners (on average ~10).  So it would likely be difficult to use `i` or any other variable as a pointer.  Is there a way for this to be set when JS first binds the listener?

Comment: wow, very good edits.  if nothing else it's very helpful for improving my code.

Comment: @cranberry - I've added a reusable function that you can use in multiple places to the end of my answer.

Comment: Wow, that was incredibly elegant.  Thank you so very much!  Have a great night (or day depending on where you are).

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that when you call `func[i]` you are just calling a string. Instead of making `func` an array of strings, consider making it an array of function references, then invoking your function with `()`

```
// a function to be called
function Alf () {
    alert("Hi! I'm Alf");
}
function Sarah () {
    alert("Hi! I'm Sarah");
}
function Jon () {
    alert("Hi! I'm Jon");
}

// an array of functions to call and a random number to choose which one to call
var func = [Alf, Sarah, Jon];
var i = Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 );

// the dynamically generated listener
$('#foo').on('click', function() {
  func[i](); //pointer to function
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tuanderful/8f5fZ/1/

Comment: Thanks.  Properly storing the function references get's me half way there.  As I said to @jfriend00, I would like to be able to use this method for a variable number of listeners (on average ~10). So reusing the `i` variable later to reference the variable once the click occurs is a problem.  I need the function call to be stored when the event listener is created.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$('#foo').on('click', function()
 {
   var i = Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 );
    eval(func[i]);//pointer to function
});
```